# Flex ANE, iOS and ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-flex, automatic-ref-counting, flash-builder

Good day

I have created a static library with Xcode. Then I compiled my ANE using adobe's ADT tool. Thereafter I've included the ANE in my FlashBuilder project. However, when attempting to package my project, I get the following error:

> "Error occurred while packaging the application:
>
> Undefined Symbols: "_obj_storeStrong", referenced from ...
>   .
>
> "_obj_release", referenced from ...
>   .
>   "

My guess is that ARC is probably not supported for ANE's. I'm guessing that this is probably due to the fact that FlashBuilder is recompiling the entire AIR + the native libs into one iOS application, probably using their own compiler or something (which is why Air apps for iOS can be compiled on windows platforms as well), and this compiler is probably not 4.3 ready yet?

I have attempted adding the flag `-fobjc-arc` to my `ios-platformoptions.xml` as well (where this file is the parameter to the `-platformoptions` flag of adt), but still no joy. It results once again in an error when packaging. Perhaps any other flag I can try to use here?

Any corrections, suggestions, alternative ideas or comments will be most welcome. I am very new to Xcode, Objective C and ANE, so please excuse any incorrect statements or assumptions, and please correct me on these.

I would be glad if somebody can please confirm weather I am correct with my assumption that I cannot use ARC at this stage on ANE's.

Thanks
Christo

Answer (score 1):

START EDIT:

Very late update, sorry.

You might be able to use ARC after all.  There is a library called arc lite that I forgot to mention and it works.  I created an ANE for MapKit on iOS targeting the 5.0.x SDK.  When I tried to move to a device that only had 4.3.x ( could have been 4.3.3 or 4.3.5 ) the app crashed or would not compile. I found information on the arc lite library that is included in the newer sdks, followed the instructions on how to include this library and pow!  A working ANE on a 4.3.x device without rewriting my code!

Hope all of this helps and half of my original comment :)

Markus

END EDIT

I don't think ARC is supported just yet.  There isn't much to go on in terms of settings or examples of what the settings should be in Xcode.  Take a look at any of the Xcode ANE projects you can get your hands on.  You will see that most or all of the projects have:

Object-C Automatice Reference counting = NO
Objective-C++ Automatic Reference counting = NO

Take a look at the following:

Vibration ANE - On Adobe Devnet site
Liquid Photo - http://www.liquid-photo.com/2011/10/30/common-native-extension-issues/

Liquid Photo - http://www.liquid-photo.com/2011/10/28/native-extension-for-adobe-air-and-ios-101/

There are a lot of examples in Github but you have to find them via Google.  Pull down the Xcode ANE projects and compare the settings.

Hope this helps!!!

Markus